# I2C Level Shifter pull up Calculation

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, i2c, pullup, interface

I am using PC9306(https://www.ti.com/product/PCA9306) for one of my project with **Vrfe2=5v** and **Vref1=1.8V**.Below is the block diagram.
[image]

My CLK is running at 100Khz.

I got the equations for pull up calculation from the application note SLVA689 from TI.Equations are given below.

[image],[image]

My questions are

1. For finding Rp(min) which VCC I need to use, 5V or 1.8V.
2. For Rp(max) calculation I need to take the rise time of My IC.Please correct me if I am wrong.
3. For bus capacitance(Cb) do I need to consider the bus capacitance of Arduino,level shifter and My IC.

Comment: Your schematic does not show the 200 kΩ resistor.

Comment: it is just a high level representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A signal line has one pull-up resistor on each side. You use both 1.8 V and 5 V.
2. t<sub>r</sub> indeed is the maximum rise time that your IC allows. The I²C specification says that this is 1 µs.
3. Yes; during a rising edge, the total bus capacitance is charged only through the pull-up resistors. Keep in mind that traces, connectors, and cables also have a capacitance.

Please note that you have two resistors in parallel. But in practice, the computed limits result in a very wide range of possible values, and most people simply use 10 kΩ.

Comment: Thank you.If I use both 1.8V and 5V Rp(min) will have two values.will that be an issue?

Comment: The limits will be so far away from 10 kΩ that it does not matter.